# getBinding() returns null in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, data-binding, nullpointerexception, null

Android DataBinding method getBinding() 
returns null when sliding tabs one by one and then step two tabs back
As far as I understand fragment is destroyed by the moment, so it's recreated, but getBinding() still returns null

Comment: Please post some of your code related to this issue.

Comment: Does it only return null in those cases? You may try findBinding instead if you are not calling it on the root of the Binding. Also, are you inflating using your Binding class in the fragment's onCreateView?